# Wrapping a Small Piece of Text with a Span with a Variable of Colour

Tags: javascript, html, colors

I am trying to 'wrap' spans around certain words within a div with a colour than can vary based on a variable.

My function so far...

```
  if (backgroundhighlightdata != null) {
      var test = "blue";
      highlightdata = cleaninputdata.replace(new RegExp('test', 'g'), "<span id='drpdownentry' class='body' style='background: "+test+";'>test</span>");
      backgroundhighlightdata.innerHTML = highlightdata;
    }
```

The colour does not seem to change at all with the variable there. But this does work.

```
  if (backgroundhighlightdata != null) {
      highlightdata = cleaninputdata.replace(new RegExp('test', 'g'), "<span id='drpdownentry' class='body' style='background: blue;'>test</span>");
      backgroundhighlightdata.innerHTML = highlightdata;
    }
```

i know I'm messing up something here, and there is most likely an easier approach to this problem.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you highlighting text first? What are the criteria or actions associated with wrapping?

Comment: Inspect rendered html. What does span looks like?

Comment: Hey guys I figured it out, the 'cleaninputdata' variable turned out to be blank so it was messing up there. thanks.